# Warning messages: 1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Timestamp'. r

Tags: r

This warning comes up every time as a chunk regardless of what I do.

```
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Timestamp'.
```

This time it's when I was reading the data

```
df<-readxl::read_xlsx("HarryPotter.xlsx)
```

I am not even sure if I have used `Timestamp` as a variable before. Does anyone know what's going wrong? Could it be that my RAM is running low? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your are probably using R Studio? I had similar warnings about columns that did not even appear in my code and asked on the R Studio help site. They said they were aware of the problem and working on it. Usually it went away after restarting R Studio and it did not happen anymore with the latest version of R Studio. So maybe you could try that?

Comment: Hi @yoland, yes I am using R Studio. I tried restart a few times and the problem did not seem to go away:/ It's Version 1.1.463 with macOS- maybe I should upgrade it later.. Thanks